# Loading images from a .dat file

Tags: file, user-interface, load

I need to know how to load saved images that are stored in my .dat file "livingroom.dat" - I am creating a GUI and want to load the images when I click on "Load File" button, after I have clicked on "Save File" - which saves my images/labels in the .dat file. I want to be able to load and display the images when I click on "Load File". I have created an ActionListener for "Load File" so just need some help with the code to load and display the stored images.